# DynamoDB and saving the child class properties in a separate table

Tags: inheritance, amazon-dynamodb

I have a class called Content and a sub-class called VideoContent.

```
[DynamoDBTable("Content")]
public class Content

[DynamoDBTable("VideoContent")]
public class VideoContent: Content
```

When I save an instance of VideoContent class, DynamoDB saves the entire class to 'VideoContent' table. I would like to write the common properties of Content and VideoContent classes to 'Content' table and only properties which are peculiar to 'VideoContent' class to 'VideoContent' table. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible using the Java SDK, though it is pretty hacky.

Look at [DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameResolver](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.java#L477) that allows you to dynamically change the table name the mapper will use.

This will give you more room to manipulate the objects before saving them to any table.

Now regarding "common" properties - in my company when we needed something similar we added a "Data" member to all objects that can represent all possible properties and by using interfaces every sub-class implemented the getter(s)/setter(s) it actually needed. This allowed us to "cast" objects around and sending a view of an object to DynamoDB to only alter part view of a table.